# reading a specific information in file

Tags: java, file

I want to read this file using `Scanner`, but not all the information, only the things after semicolon like 10, warrior, John Smith and so on.

```
currhp: 10

type: Warrior

name: John Smith

items:
      Stick,1,2,10,5

gold: 10

type: Wizard
```

I tried to solve it but i couldn't.

```java
Scanner infile;

Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);

try {

 infile =    new Scanner(new File("player_save.txt"));

} catch    (FileNotFoundException o) {

 System.out.println(o); return; }

while (infile.hasNextLine()) { 

System.out.println(infile.nextLine()); 

}
```

Comment: Can you give more details about the problem? Have you got some error messages? How does your problem relate to Javascript?

Comment: I want to read the information in this file but without the String after  this sign ":"
without ( currhp: , type:  ,name: , items:  ,gold:  ,type: )  because i want put these information in a class to use them later on.
 I hope  the idea has reached to you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to open file, read line by line and then split each line and use the chunk of the line that you wish to do further processing on it.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReadFile{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //fix the URL to where your file is located.
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\player_save.txt"))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if(line.length() > 0) {
                      if(line.contains(":")) {
                          System.out.println("Before colon >> " + line.split(":")[0]);  
                       } else {
                          //no column found taking the whole line
                         System.out.println("whole line having no coln: " + line);                    
                     }
                }
            }
        } catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe) {   
          //Handle scenario where the file does not exist   
        } catch(IOException ie) {
          //Handle other File I/O exceptions here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for that, added .contains(":") validation. There might be other cases but his question is not clear. What do you mean the update still fails?

Comment: You edited your question but forgot to add line.contains(":") or anything else for that matter. But now you have. Good job

Comment: Cheers, since you removed your +1 I will give you another anyway for pointing the java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException :)

Comment: the cod that i've already put it there is no error on it but what i mean is i tried to solve it many time but i couldn't .and to make the question more clear , I want to read the information in this file but without the String after  this sign ":"
without ( currhp: , type:  ,name: , items:  ,gold:  ,type: ) to put it in a class and use it later on .

Comment: I have updated the code to print you the strings that is to the left side of the colon. Basically I first check to make sure that the line contains text, if yes, then I check if it contains colon or not. If the line contains colon the I split it using ":" and return the first element of the array that would be value to the left of colon. If no colon was found then I return the print the whole line. You should be able to modify the code as per your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this -

```
List<String> list= new ArrayList<>();
    try(
    Scanner scan= new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("//your filepath")));
    ){      

    while(scan.hasNextLine()){
        String s=scan.nextLine();
        if(s.contains(":")){
            String arr[]=s.split(":");
            list.add(arr[1].trim());
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    for(String str:list){
        System.out.println(str);
    }
```